# What happens with ECHO via \write18?

Tags: shell-escape

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{echo '\detokenize{\hi \foo \hi}' > x.txt}
\end{document}
```

The content of `x.txt` contains:

```
\hi
    oo \hi
```

What happened to `\f`? Also, how can I make sure `\foo` shows up in the file?

Comment: that is OS-dependent for me with bash `echo '\foo'` makes `\foo` but  `echo -e '\foo'`  makes `<form-feed> oo` it appears your `echo` is defaulting `-e` and taking `\f` as a control character escape, so you would need `\\foo` (just typing on the commandline, not via tex at all)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right! If you post an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is OS-dependent for me with bash
`echo '\foo'`
makes
`\foo`
but
`echo -e '\foo'`
makes
`<form-feed> oo`

it appears your `echo` is defaulting `-e` and taking `\f` as a control character escape, so you would need `\\foo` (just typing on the commandline, not via tex at all)

Comment: This is the solution: `\immediate\write18{/bin/echo '\detokenize{\hi \foo \hi}' > x.txt}`

Comment: @yegor256 so long as you have no users on windows